# Scrapy redirected from productlink to very strange domain

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

After testing my crawler, something strange happened to me.(at least its strange for me)

I got redirected to `http://www.pangea.nl`
This site has only a yellow screen, with red "pangea" string...

**Domain I wanted to crawl**
https://www.duif.nl

**My console output**
[image: click me]

I'm kind of scared now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at your code, it is hard to say exactly why you landed on that page.
However the webpage that you crawled: https://www.duif.nl/product/mirror-yeu-brown

Has a link to that website. You can view it if you look at the source of the page: [view-source:https://www.duif.nl/product/mirror-yeu-brown](http://view-source:https://www.duif.nl/product/mirror-yeu-brown)

The link is also visible in the footer of the page while viewing on a mobile device:

[image]

---

You could easily avoid this page by adding [allowed domains](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.allowed_domains) to your spider's settings.

```
allowed_domains = ["duif.nl"]
```

Comment: well that explains a lot.. i was just  kind of confused because that page looked so strange to me, also didnt check the footer >:(